# Call PHP from Ruby and get response

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got an open source charity website that is built in Ruby on Rails and we're trying to integrate a payment validation system and one already exists in PHP - trying to find if there is a way to get these two to play nice together?

Can I call the PHP script from Ruby and have Ruby read any echo'd response etc?

Comment: We need more information. What do you mean "call"? Launch it in a sub-shell? Open a HTTP session to it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can be done using system calls as such

```
def your_method(path,file)
  system("cd #{path} && #{file} ")
end
```

Btw, know that there is the `IO` class for all input/output and one of the fundamental method command is

```
def popen(cmd)
        Open3.popen3(cmd) {|stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr|
          exit_status = wait_thr.value
          if (exit_status !=0)
            raise CommandError, "Something went wrong" // supposing you customize class //Command < StandardError ; end
          end
        }
      end
```

On antoher side, if both codes runs on different codes, it is of course for you possible to "apize" your rails app, in order to fetch and pull data

Answer (score 1):

There is two ways you can do this.

1. Shell exec the php payment script (if available) check [Ruby shell exec](http://tech.natemurray.com/2007/03/ruby-shell-commands.html)
   this will only be usefull if the payment system can work via [CLI](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php)
2. HTTP request from ruby, check the [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTPRequest.html) and using this way you can "replicate" the way the php payment system works online. Sending the correct `POST` / `GET` data and make it work.